# Adding Text Area in JavaFX when using TextField

Tags: java, javafx

I've previously mentioned I am only getting back to into JavaFX due to a final year college project. I have created a IP / Mac Address finder per say. As part of this I will run an arp command and return back the information from the arp command. I've come across an issue with the text field being too small for all the arp information returned. When I put in a text area my gridpane is reconfigured and misaligned. Would any one be able to advise how to add the text area in? The area I am talking about is in the ** section

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Wi-FI Connection Checker");

        //GridPane with 10px padding around edge
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        //Name Label - constrains use (child, column, row)
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Find my IP Address:");
        nameLabel.setId("bold-label");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameLabel, 0, 0);

        //Search IP Address 
        Button IPlookupButton =new Button("Search for IP");
        GridPane.setConstraints(IPlookupButton, 3, 0);

        //Name Input
        TextField nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("IP Address");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 1, 0);

        IPlookupButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                nameInput.setText("IP:" + thisIp.getHostAddress());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        //MAC Address Lookup Label
        Label passLabel = new Label("MAC Address Look UP:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passLabel, 0, 1);

        //MAC Address Input
        TextField passInput = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("MAC Address");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passInput, 1, 1);

        //Search MAC Address 
        Button MacAddressButton =new Button("Search for MAC Address");
        GridPane.setConstraints(MacAddressButton, 3, 1);


        //MAC Address Input
        TextField MacFound = new TextField();
        GridPane.setConstraints(MacFound, 1, 2);


        //MAC Vendor Label
        Label vendorLabel = new Label("Manufacturer Make:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(vendorLabel, 0, 2);

        //MAC Address Search 
        MacAddressButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {

            String MacAddress = passInput.getText();


            URL oracle = new URL("https://api.macvendors.com/"+ MacAddress);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                MacFound.setText(inputLine);
                MacFound.setPrefWidth(MacFound.getText().length() * 7);
            in.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        );

        //Wi-Fi Connection Button
        Button WifiButton = new Button("Search my Wi-Fi");
        GridPane.setConstraints(WifiButton, 1, 3);

        TextField WifiInfo = new TextField();
        //textArea.setPrefRowCount(4);
        GridPane.setConstraints(WifiInfo, 1, 4);

        **WifiButton.setOnAction(event -> {

            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a");
                process.waitFor();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.ready()) {
                    i++;
                    String ip = reader.readLine();
                    if (i >= 4) {
                        ip = ip.substring(2, 56) + "\n";
                    }
                    WifiInfo.setText(ip);
                    WifiInfo.setPrefWidth(WifiInfo.getText().length() * 7);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }**

        });

        //Add everything to grid
        grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, IPlookupButton, nameInput, passLabel, passInput,MacAddressButton, MacFound, vendorLabel, WifiButton, WifiInfo);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("colour.css");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your WinfiInfo to `TextArea`.

```
TextArea WifiInfo = new TextArea();
```

Then add/change code accordingly.

```
grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, IPlookupButton, nameInput, passLabel, passInput, MacAddressButton, MacFound, vendorLabel, WifiButton);

VBox root = new VBox(grid, WifiInfo);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
```

This code makes the root a `VBox` and adds the `GridPane` and the `TextArea` to it. You can set padding or margins on the `TextArea`.

[image]

Comment: java naming convention, please .. <g> or in other words: better not replicate the errors in the question

Comment: @kleopatra this is an old one. I will keep this in mind for new questions.

Answer (score 0):

**We can specify rowspan and colspan**

```
  TextArea dataFld = new TextArea();
   //column=0, row=5, colspan=3, rowspan=3
  gridPane.add(dataFld, 0, 5, 3, 3);

  //Creating a scene object 
  Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
  
  //Setting title to the Stage 
  stage.setTitle("Grid Pane Example"); 
     
  //Adding scene to the stage 
  stage.setScene(scene); 
     
  //Displaying the contents of the stage 
  stage.show();
```